# How can I create a single view page in Wordpress for a custom table

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I have a custom table in my wordpress website, called **wp_flowers**.
Every flower has a single view page. I have created a template `single-flower-template.php`. But how can I activate this template for a single view?

I cannot use the default Wordpress method: because my flower table is **not** a custom post type. So I cannot use `single-flower.php` or `single.php`.

My other attempt: I have created a default page where I attached my template and where I loaded the flower `?flower_id=123` from the url. But this a bad practice for SEO (wrong page title, etc).

Who knows a good solution for this problem?

Comment: you can write custom rewrite rules so your URLs are SEO friendly but still work at querying the DB based on URL parameters ref: https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

Comment: another reference: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/250837/understanding-add-rewrite-rule